# First singular cohomology of $n$-torus minus $k$ points

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathbb T^n=\left(S^1\right)^n$ be the $n$-torus and $A\subseteq\mathbb T^n$ be a finite non-empty subset of cardinality $k$. Then what is the first singular cohomology of $\mathbb T^n\setminus A$?

Eg: $\mathbb T^2\setminus A$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^{k+1}S^1$. Thus $H^1\left(\mathbb T^2\setminus A,\mathbb Z\right)\cong\mathbb Z^{k+1}$

Comment: Think of $\mathbb{T}^3$ as a cube under identification of oposite faces and reason similarly to what you did to deduce the homotopy type of $\mathbb{T}^2\setminus A$, what happens in that case? can you generalize it to higher dimensions?

Comment: I can't really see it. I think it's a wedge sum of spheres, but I am not sure.